# CSS display div on another div:hover

Tags: html, css

I want to display the `p` elements on top of the images (the IDs are used for CSS background images) when I hover over the album elements (the images). I have tried the following:

```css
.album {
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  background-color: gray;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#gallery .album p {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
}

.album:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(50%);
}

.album:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul id="gallery">
    <li id="nsfm" class="album">
        <p>New Shapes for Madness LP - 2014</p>
    </li>
    <li id="unsettled" class="album">
        <p>Unsettled EP - 2013</p>
    </li>
    <li id="aptw" class="album">
        <p>A Path to Wrath LP - 2012</p>
    </li>
    <li id="pfw" class="album">
        <p>Pieces from Wasteland EP - 2011</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have also tried `display:none;` and `display:block` on `:hover` but none seem to be working for me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The images are background-images?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of this? My guess is that the `:hover` effect is not overriding your `#gallery .album p` selector.

Comment: Yeah if looks like thats the issue @Aeolingamenfel

Comment: Awesome, glad to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a quick fix just make the declarations on the `.album:hover p` class important, and add a transition to the p tag.

```
#gallery .album p {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.album:hover p {
    visibility:visible !important;
    opacity:1 !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w3hutbu8/

**A better fix:**

This happens because your `#gallery .album p` styling is overriding the `.album:hover p` one (an ID is more "important" than a class).

You can either remove the `#gallery` from `#gallery .album p` or add it to `.album:hover p` and then it will work without the `!important` tag.

```css
.album {
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  background-color: gray;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.album p {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
}

.album:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(50%);
}

.album:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul id="gallery">
    <li id="nsfm" class="album">
        <p>New Shapes for Madness LP - 2014</p>
    </li>
    <li id="unsettled" class="album">
        <p>Unsettled EP - 2013</p>
    </li>
    <li id="aptw" class="album">
        <p>A Path to Wrath LP - 2012</p>
    </li>
    <li id="pfw" class="album">
        <p>Pieces from Wasteland EP - 2011</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much! Any idea on why the code doesn't work without the !important tag?

Comment: Thats because your `#gallery .album p` styling is overriding the `.album:hover p` one (an ID is more "important" than a class). You can either remove the `#gallery` from `#gallery .album p` or add it to `.album:hover p` and then it will work with the `!important` tag. @FaustoNA

Comment: I have edited this old question to make it more readable. After some time, I no longer consider your answer appropriate, but this last comment you made answers it better ('you can either remove the `#gallery` from `#gallery .album p` or add it to `.album:hover p`'). I am considering deleting the question, but if you modify your answer with your comment I will keep it.

Comment: @FaustoNA - "I am considering deleting the question..." You cannot delete it as it has been answered and voted on.  These types of questions are not delete able unless you are a moderator.

Comment: I see! I took a different approach and edited the answer myself. See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333943/old-answer-which-i-no-longer-consider-correct-what-is-the-best-approach
Thanks btw!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correct... This will work for you. :)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYjgmy

```
.album p {
  opacity:0;
}

.album:hover p {
  opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With some modification to your code it can results as you desired. There may be some other ways to do this, but they can be other answers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title></title>
       <style type="text/css">
        .album {
          width:230px;
        height:230px;
        background-color:grey;
        float:left;
        list-style:none;
        position:relative;
       -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
       -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
       -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
       -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
       }

      p {
        position: absolute;
       top:0;
       display: none;
       width:100%;
      height: 50px;
      text-align:center;
      bottom:50px;
        }

           .album:hover p{
         display: block;
        font-size: 20px;
              }
       .album:hover{
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(50%);

           }

        </style>

         </head>
            <body>

       <ul id="gallery">
          <li id="nsfm" class="album"><p>New Shapes for Madness LP - 2014</p></li>
      <li id="unsettled" class="album"><p>Unsettled EP - 2013</p></li>
     <li id="aptw" class="album"><p>A Path to Wrath LP - 2012</p></li>
    <li id="pfw" class="album"><p>Pieces from Wasteland EP - 2011</p></li>
    </ul>


</body>
</html>
```